# Passing only a subset of the method parameters to the advice

Tags: java, parameters, aspectj, signature

```java
public class MyClass {

    public void myMethod(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e, String f) {
        return true;
    }

}

public aspect MyAspect {

    pointcut myPointcut(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e, String f):
        execution (public void myMethod(String, String, String, String, String, String)) &&
        target(MyClass) &&
        args(a, b, c, d, e, f);

    after(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e, String f) : myPointcut(a, b, c, d, e, f) {
        // I only need parameter "b"
    }

}
```

I there any way to pass only the arg `String b` to my advice, since I don't need the other ones here?

I tried by any chance the following:

```java
pointcut myPointcut(String b):
    execution (public void myMethod(String, String, String, String, String, String)) &&
    target(MyClass) &&
    args(b);

after(String b) : myPointcut(b) {
    // I only need parameter "b"
}
```

But I get the following warning:

```
advice defined in MyAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I can see without changing the method signatures.  The parameter names are lost at runtime so there would be no correlation between your advice and the method signature that triggered it.  In other words it wouldn't know what String to pass.

To clarify, the following is compiled to the same as your code above.  We don't know which of the 6 strings is the one you require:

```
pointcut myPointcut(String someString):
    execution (public void myMethod(String, String, String, String, String, String)) &&
    target(MyClass) &&
    args(someString);

after(String someString) : myPointcut(someString) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution to this would be the usage of the so called `varargs`. Change the signature of `myMethod` to:

```
public boolean myMethod(String... args) { return true; }
```

Then, you can pass as much as `String` objects you'd like and you can access them like accessing elements from an array. For example, to get the first one, you need to do:

```
String first = args[0];
```